# How to make nose plugin startTest method to return info about the test

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

Ive created this demo plugin to see how plugins work: (only thing added is the `startTest` method)

```
import logging 
import os
from nose.plugins import Plugin
import nose

log = logging.getLogger('nose.plugins.helloworld')

class HelloWorld(Plugin):
    name = 'helloworld'

    def options(self, parser, env=os.environ):
        super(HelloWorld, self).options(parser, env=env)

    def configure(self, options, conf):
        super(HelloWorld, self).configure(options, conf)
        if not self.enabled:
            return

    def finalize(self, result):
        log.info('Hello pluginized world!')

    def startTest(self, test):
        print "startTest method was run"
        print test.__doc__
```

But when running a test with this plugin , instead of getting the `__doc__` of the test, 
im getting the universal test case wrapper doc.

```
startTest method was run
The universal test case wrapper.

When a plugin sees a test, it will always see an instance of this
class. To access the actual test case that will be run, access the
test property of the nose.case.Test instance.
```

I cant figure out how to `access test property of the nose.case.test`
Ive tried to use `print nose.case.Test.__test__` but this returns a `bool` value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would inject `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in your startTest() function and have a nice look at `test` instance in the debugger. I'm sure the information you are looking for is there, it just might be few levels down. Do not forget to add `-s` to your nosetests run to enable stdout interaction with your debugger.

*Edit:* I just did just that with a basic function test. For this particular case, the doc was under `test.test.test.__doc__`. The test was defined as:

```
def test_a():
    "mydoc"
    pass
```

Note: do not forget to actually enable your plugin by setting `self.enable=True`.

Comment: Ive tried it and for me it worked with `test.test.__doc__` 
Thank you!